# Jquery Dialog Not coming On Top Other dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have Two Dialog box one upon another,

on Clicking Ok of One dialog box,

on invalid entry other box will appear ,

but some time outer dialog box getting in of First dialog box.please suggest me the way so that it come one upon anather every time.

```
.dialog({
    , title: $title
    , modal: true
    , width: width
    , height: height
    , resizable: resizable
    , pos: top,
 });
```

first time it is coming on top form next time its is getting in of first one

can any one explain on this:

Use the dialogClass option on the higher dialog to assign a class that has z-index = 2.

Comment: post your code or  create a [*fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: code in question is not enough to get what your problem is better create a fiddle

Comment: Use the `dialogClass` option on the higher dialog to assign a class that has z-index = 2.

Comment: hi salman whr i have to assingn z index to outer on or inner one please explain me funda of z index hw to use ...more exp not present of jquery site